# Program ending with status 3 SDL

Tags: c, sdl

The following program is ending with status 3 every time I'm starting it.

```
#include "amr-0-1.h"
#include "SDL_sys.c"

int screen_w=351, screen_h=234;
int ss_w=screen_w*(5/9), ss_h=screen_h*(11/19);
int m_w=screen_w*(7/27), m_h=screen_h*(175/234);
int g_w=screen_w*(100/351), g_h=screen_h*(2/9);
int mo_w=screen_w*(29/117), mo_h=screen_h*(1/13);
int ss_mo_w=screen_w*(17/117), ss_mo_h=screen_h*(4/117);
int p_d=32, border=2;

SDL_Surface *screen = NULL; //Fenetre principale
SDL_Surface *m = NULL;      //Surface du menu
SDL_Surface *mo = NULL;     //Surface d'une option menu
SDL_Surface *ss = NULL;     //Surface de la zone d'écran secondaire
SDL_Surface *ss_mo = NULL;  //Surface d'une option du sous-menu
SDL_Surface *p = NULL;      //Surface destinée à accueillir l'image utilisateur

SDL_Rect c_m;
SDL_Rect c_mo;
SDL_Rect c_ss;
SDL_Rect c_ss_mo;
SDL_Rect c_p;
SDL_Rect c_screen;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO) == -1)
{
fprintf(stderr, "Erreur d'initialisation de la SDL");
exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
SGI_Init(1, screen, 351, 234, NULL, 0, 0, &c_screen); //Écran principal
SGI_Init(0, m, m_w, m_h, screen, 39, 58, &c_m); //Menu
SGI_Init(0, ss, ss_w, ss_h, screen, 156, 78, &c_ss); //Surface d'écran secondaire
pause();
SDL_Quit();
return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

According to my research, status 3 stand for 'SegFault', so it's an allocation problem with one (or more) of the SDL' surface. Here is how I allocate the surface:

```
#include "amr-0-1.h"

void pause()
{
int continuer = 1;
SDL_Event event;

while (continuer)
{
SDL_WaitEvent(&event);
switch(event.type)
{
case SDL_QUIT:
continuer = 0;
}
}
}

int SGI_Init(int command, SDL_Surface *child, int child_w, int child_h, SDL_Surface *mother, int x, int y, SDL_Rect* cursor)
{
if(command)
{
child = SDL_SetVideoMode(child_w, child_h, 32, SDL_HWSURFACE | SDL_DOUBLEBUF);
return 1;
}
else if(!command)
{
child = SDL_CreateRGBSurface(SDL_HWSURFACE, child_w, child_h, 32, 0,0,0,0);
SDL_FillRect(child, cursor, SDL_MapRGB(mother->format,255,255,255));
cursor->x=x;
cursor->y=y;
SDL_BlitSurface(child, NULL, mother, cursor);
SDL_Flip(mother);
return 1;
}
else
{
return 0;
}
}
```

The header amr-0-1.h:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <SDL.h>

void pause();
int SGI_Init(int command, SDL_Surface *child, int child_w, int child_h, SDL_Surface *mother, int x, int y, SDL_Rect* cursor);
```

I can't find why my allocation is incorrect.
I'm using SDL 1.2 and CodeBlocks 17.12, also I'm a noob and I'm French, so please be patient I'm slow!

Comment: Run it in GDB and get a stack trace when it crashes and take a look at the state of relevant variables at the time of crashing.  Should give you a good start in figuring out the problem.

Comment: What is `SDL_sys.c`?

Comment: Modifying local parameter `child` in `SGI_Init` (i.e. `child = SDL_SetVideoMode` and so on) will not change value of `screen` on calling side because it is, well, *local*. If you need to modify variable passed to function, you either return new value from function or pass address of variable and use pointer dereference.

Comment: @genpfault, it's where I want to put all my functions related to SDL.

Comment: @keltar, do you think that will impact the status 3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The immediate SEGFAULT is probably caused by

```
SDL_FillRect(child, cursor, SDL_MapRGB(mother->format,255,255,255));
```

The reason behind this is answered in the comment of keltar:

In this line:

```
SGI_Init(1, screen, 351, 234, NULL, 0, 0, &c_screen);
```

you pass in `screen` in order to initialize it. 
What happens here is that the *value* of `screen` is copied into the *local* variable `child`.
You then modify `child`, but this happens to the *copy* of `screen`, `screen` itself stays the same.
You are probably confused by the fact that `screen` is a pointer.
However, you want to modify the pointer, and therefore you require a *pointer to a pointer* like this:

```
int SGI_Init(int command, SDL_Surface **child, int child_w, int child_h, SDL_Surface *mother, int x, int y, SDL_Rect* cursor)
    {

        if(command)
        {
            *child = SDL_SetVideoMode(child_w, child_h, 32, SDL_HWSURFACE | SDL_DOUBLEBUF);
            return 1;
        }
        else if(!command)
        {
            *child = SDL_CreateRGBSurface(SDL_HWSURFACE, child_w, child_h, 32, 0,0,0,0);
            SDL_FillRect(*child, cursor, SDL_MapRGB(mother->format,255,255,255));
            cursor->x=x;
            cursor->y=y;
            SDL_BlitSurface(*child, NULL, mother, cursor);
            SDL_Flip(mother);
            return 1;
        }
        else
        {
            return 0;
        }
    }


    int main(int argc, char *argv[])
    {
        if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO) == -1)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "Erreur d'initialisation de la SDL");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        SGI_Init(1, &screen, 351, 234, NULL, 0, 0, &c_screen); //Écran principal
        printf("%p\n", screen);
    SGI_Init(0, &m, m_w, m_h, screen, 39, 58, &c_m); //Menu
    SGI_Init(0, &ss, ss_w, ss_h, screen, 156, 78, &c_ss); //Surface d'écran secondaire
        pause();
        SDL_Quit();
        return EXIT_SUCCESS;
    }
```

But why not just return the new `SDL_Surface` like so:

```
SDL_Surface* SGI_Init(int command, int child_w, int child_h, SDL_Surface *mother, int x, int y, SDL_Rect* cursor)
{

    if(command)
    {
        return SDL_SetVideoMode(child_w, child_h, 32, SDL_HWSURFACE | SDL_DOUBLEBUF);
    }
    else if(!command)
    {
        SDL_Surface* child = SDL_CreateRGBSurface(SDL_HWSURFACE, child_w, child_h, 32, 0,0,0,0);
        SDL_FillRect(child, cursor, SDL_MapRGB(mother->format,255,255,255));
        cursor->x=x;
        cursor->y=y;
        SDL_BlitSurface(child, NULL, mother, cursor);
        SDL_Flip(mother);
        return child;
    }
    else
    {
        return 0;
    }
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO) == -1)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Erreur d'initialisation de la SDL");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    screen = SGI_Init(1, 351, 234, NULL, 0, 0, &c_screen); //Écran principal
    printf("%p\n", screen);
    m = SGI_Init(0, m_w, m_h, screen, 39, 58, &c_m); //Menu
    ss = SGI_Init(0, ss_w, ss_h, screen, 156, 78, &c_ss); //Surface d'écran secondaire
    pause();
    SDL_Quit();
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

There are a few things in your code that might cause undefined behaviour, like

```
SDL_Rect c_m;
SDL_Rect c_mo;
SDL_Rect c_ss;
...
```

declare the variables, but you never initialize them, you just pass them in to functions as parameters. If one of them is ever read before initialization, it inflicts undefined behaviour.

Even so, there are a lot of code smells in there, the most striking one is obvious by the `command` parameter: Your `SDI_Init` function does two entirely different things. You should try to stick to the [single responsibility principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle) and split the function up into 2 functions - one per task. If you want to stick to your design, at least resort back to using an appropriate `enum` for `command`...

Comment: It seems to work but I can't tell because I have a black window instead of a black & white window.

Comment: Yes, well, You asked for help finding the root cause of the SEGV.  I don't know about a black&white window - you do not mention anything about that. Sorry, but answering questions that never have been posed is beyond my abilities ;) To debug stuff like this in the future, I advise to get to know mem checkers like valgrind . otherwise you will end in memory bug hell...

Comment: 'otherwise you will end in memory bug hell' XD